# What is the `post-status` icon handle when using `@wordpress/icons`?

Tags: icon

I'm trying to use the [`@wordpress/icons`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@wordpress/icons) npm package:

```
npm install @wordpress/icons --save
```

To display the [`dashicons-post-status`](https://developer.wordpress.org/resource/dashicons/#post-status) icon within the block editor:

```js
import { Icon, postStatus } from '@wordpress/icons';

<Icon icon={ postStatus } />;
```

**The issue -** As far as I can tell, this icon doesn't exist within the [icons package](https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/tree/trunk/packages/icons). Either that, or I'm utterly blind and need my eyes tested? Would one of you lovely people be able to confirm what I'm not seeing?

I appreciate any help.

**Note:** I've also asked this question in the [`wordpress.org/gutenberg`](https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/discussions/43630) repo on Github for more exposure. [Link to thread discussion.](https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/discussions/43630)

Comment: Hello, These icons are dashicons available in WordPress Core. This is surely a sprite css

Comment: @SébastienSerre I was under the impression that the `dashicons` were ported to `gutenburg`, and added to the `@wordpress/icons` package for use in gutes react development. Am I wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So after a little digging and being maybe a little bit oblivious . The correct way to use `dashicons` within WordPress is as follows;

```js
import { Dashicon } from "@wordpress/components";

<Dashicon icon="post-status" />
```

**Note:** This info can be found in the [`Developer Resources: Dashicons`](https://developer.wordpress.org/resource/dashicons/#post-status) docs, but annoyingly it is buried at the bottom of the page. There are no links to this info at the top of the page, so I didn't even know it existed.

**Anyways**, here's a [direct link](https://developer.wordpress.org/resource/dashicons/#instructions) to the instructions on how to use `Dashicons` from `@wordpress/components` You'll find the specifics under **Block Usage**.